# Background synchronization similar to Dropbox, but for custom storage

Tags: linux, file-synchronization

Suppose I have some network-accessible storage, like an NFS mount, [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) mount or [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). These are all immediate mode storage systems, i.e. when I copy a file to the mount, it is immediately uploaded, and the operation blocks until the upload is finished. Similarly for downloading, files have to always be re-downloaded on opening.

I'm looking for a program which would, given a directory on a local filesystem, synchronize it with the above mentioned storage in background. To the user this program with such storage should look very similar to Dropbox: put a file in the directory — and it gets uploaded in background, something changed on the remote storage — and soon you have the change reflected in you local directory.

Is there such a (freeware) program? I'd prefer opensource one.

Comment: Have not tried it myself, but googling for "inotify rsync" (which was the first coming to my mind here) brought up [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd), which from its description sounds like it matches your needs. Not sure whether it works bidirectional, though. [Here](http://blog.remoteminds.it/lsyncd-inotify-rsync-admin-heaven/) is a more detailed German blog article on it. Another alternative would be [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), which I also wanted to look at for some time but never managed...

Comment: I also think `lsyncd` would be your choice, I described it in this answer https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36797/what-is-simple-way-to-sync-contents-in-my-local-computer-to-the-contents-in-a-re/36862#36862.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I've tried lsyncd, and it appears to not quite suite me: it's asymmetrical by nature, meaning that it downloads remote changes to a local directory ("Source" to "Target" in its terminology), but doesn't upload local changes to remote directory.